# I am trying to reduce the opacity of certain objects but it is not working for me

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a question that I have taken a column/box in HTML which includes certain images and text and when I try to reduce the opacity of that column it reduces the opacity of the images as well that are inside it. I have given different class to the column and images, but this is not working for me and it is reducing the opacity of all the contents in it. Please let me know that what should be done to solve it?

Comment: Please post some code for what you have tried and what is not working. Please see [How to create  a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`background-color: rgba(r,g,b,alpha[0,1])`

or

`background-color:hsla(hue, saturation, lightness, alpha[0,1])`

instead of using opacity in .container

https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/func_rgba.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_hsla.asp

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);

  /* opacity: 0.1; */
}

.container:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300?apple" alt="" />
    </div>
```